# How can I deploy a Node Express and React app to Heroku, after running with Travis CI?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, deployment, travis-ci

**Following Setup:**

- A Node Express server, running on localhost:5000.
- A client folder created with `create-react-app` directly in the server folder.
- CI Integration with Travis CI

I want to deploy my app to heroku when it's passing. Therefore I created following `.travis.yml`:

```
language: node_js
before_install: 
  - npm install && node index.js &
before_script: cd ./client && npm install
node_js:
  - "stable"
cache:
  directories:
  - node_modules
script:
  - npm run test
  - npm run lint
  - npm run build
notifications:
    slack: clicker-web:myslack
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key: "mykey"
  app: test999111test
  on: heroku-deployment-testing
```

So I got it to deploy to heroku and not failing with travis. 
But in the heroku app itself I just get the error (in the console):

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-04-15T15:15:31.033343+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2018-04-15T15:15:31.034412+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Clicker@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
2018-04-15T15:15:31.034622+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2018-04-15T15:15:31.034841+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2018-04-15T15:15:31.035019+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the Clicker@0.1.0 start script.
```

So I'm pretty sure it has to be something wrong with my setup.

This is the `package.json` I have set up in the server (root) directory (just a snippet of code you need):

```
"engines": {
    "node": "8.1.1",
    "npm": "5.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "buildclient": "npm build --prefix client",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "dev":
      "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "build": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "test": "npm run server",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild":
      "npm run install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

I use a proxy in my application for development which is working just fine. But in prod on heroku I don't need it. I have created these lines in the `index.js` (in server root):

```
const path = require("path");
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});
```

But I always get the same error from Heroku. What did I do wrong and how to deploy a project with server + client combined to heroku from Travis with best practice?

Here is the Project, where you can see the file structure. I'm on the `heroku-deployment-testing` branch right now.

[Github Repo](https://github.com/click-web-game/Clicker-server/tree/heroku-deployment-testing)

Also here is the herokuapp which isn't showing anything besides an error:

[Heroku App](https://test999111test.herokuapp.com/)

**Last but not least the travis logs (the last part where it's deploying):**

[image]

Comment: Now that you've shared it publicly, you need to revoke your Heroku API key. Also note that SO doesn't support GitHub-flavored markdown.

Comment: Done, thx for the info! Ok what's wrong with my markdown? Is it too long you think? I tried it with the code tag where you see "paste code here" , but it messed it up really hard

Comment: You didn't read the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: You'll also want to revoke your mlab credentials and google secret. Don't commit your `.env` to a public repository.

Comment: Damn. Will do. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this config

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- '8'
cache:
  directories:
  - node_modules
  - client/node_modules
install:
- npm install
- npm run build
script:
- nohup npm run start &
- sleep 3
- npm run test
- npm run lint
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: API_KEY
  app: YOUR_APP_NAME
```

I believe you don't need `before_install` and `before_script` sections.

And also you don't need to run `npm run build` script since you're building your application with "heroku_postbuild" script in your package.json.